# Calculate Percentage from Count of Two Tables

Tags: sql-server, group-by

I have the following that returns the counts from two tables

```
USE CBA

SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT dat.CoAc) AS Count1
FROM
    (SELECT *
     FROM IR20181125
     WHERE pdate NOT IN ('NULL','')) dat

SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT CoAc) As Count2
FROM 
    IPR20181125
```

I need to work out the percentage so (Count1*100)/Count2, but I am unsure of the syntax to do that.

Edit - I need the answer correct to 2 decimal places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select (
 Select (COUNT(DISTINCT dat.CoAc) * 100) AS Count1 /*count1 * 100*/
 From(
  Select *
  From IR20181125
  where pdate not in ('NULL','')
 ) dat
) / (
 Select COUNT(DISTINCT CoAc) As Count2
 From IPR20181125
) CountPercentage
```

Let me know, what did you got.

**Update 1**

```
select (
 Select convert (decimal (18,2), (COUNT(DISTINCT dat.CoAc) * 100)) AS Count1 
 From(
  Select *
  From IR20181125
  where pdate not in ('NULL','')
 ) dat
) / (
 Select convert (decimal (18,2), COUNT(DISTINCT CoAc)) As Count2
 From IPR20181125
) CountPercentage
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked but I need it to 2 decimal places, can that be done?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need separate selects to get these counts. You can get them at once:

```
Select
    COUNT(DISTINCT case when pdate not in ('NULL','') then CoAc else NULL end) As Count1
    , COUNT(DISTINCT CoAc) As Count2
From IR20181125
```

Hence you can calculate the percentage directly:

```
Select COUNT(DISTINCT case when pdate not in ('NULL','') then CoAc else NULL end) * 100.0 / COUNT(DISTINCT CoAc)
From IR20181125
```

In case your counts are coming from different tables, you can use sub-queries to calculate both counts, and single select without from, to calculate the percentage:

```
select 
    100.0 * (
        Select COUNT(DISTINCT CoAc) as Cnt
        From IR20181125
        where pdate not in ('NULL','')
    ) / (
        select COUNT(DISTINCT CoAc) as Cnt
        from SecondTable
    )
```

Comment: I've edited the question as I made an error, there are two tables, sorry!

Comment: In this case you can replace the counts in the expression `select 100.0 * Cnt1 / Cnt2` with subqueries. I will update my answer to show you how.